# Conversation logs open data

Tags: nlp

Is there any open data on conversation logs?

I am looking for open data on conversation logs, yes between individual people. Ideally private chat logs. I am considering using a bot to scrape a website like Omegle which has a "ask a question" mode letting two users discuss a topic, but It would be easier if someone recommended a open data set to me.

Just for elaboration, I am doing some things with topic modeling, so This would be useful for my study.

Comment: for its size, the [enron corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_Corpus) may work for you. It has more than 600k emails, most of which are very chatting and inconsequential.